# Flutter: Print to console from Dart isolates?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Having trouble finding information about this online. I'm just trying to figure out if a particular function in a Dart isolate is actually being run. The only way I know how to do this is by using the `print()` function, but either my function isn't being run, or `print()`s from an isolate don't show up in the console using `flutter run`. I don't even know which is the case.

Here is the code that I'm trying to verify is being run, namely the `onStart` function:

```
void _entrypoint() => AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  
  onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    print('*** HELLO ***');
  }
}
```

This is the calling code, from the state of the Flutter app:

```
  initAudio() async {
    // Not sure if this is necessary, but according to some, it is.
    await AudioService.connect();

    // This should run the `onStart` function above.
    await AudioService.start(backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _entrypoint);

    print('*** THIS IS RUNNING ***');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initAudio();
  }
```

`initAudio()` is indeed being run, as proven by the `print()` statement within.

So the question is: Can I `print()` from a Dart isolate, and if not, how can I make an isolate somehow indicate that it is being run at all?

All of this is just to try and get the Flutter package [`audio_service`](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/0.16.2/) working (version 0.16.2, specifically). I've been stuck at this point, just figuring out if the `onStart` is being run at all. As far as I can tell, it isn't being run, but I don't have a way to prove it.

(Bonus question: If it **isn't** being run, I wonder why not. But that makes the question `audio_service`-specific, which probably merits a separate question. I am already using doing `home: AudioServiceWidget(child:...` and `_entrypoint` is top-level.)

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that stdout from an isolate will be the same as the main isolate. You can pretty easily make a little sample program to check.

Comment: And I'm *pretty sure* that Isolates have no interface except for ports, or else they'd mess up the UI Isolate's access to those.

Comment: try check `flutter logs` for your print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten an isolate to work, and the answer is **yes**, the printed strings should be visible from within an isolate, at least in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

yes, isolates prints are visible on the log. For some cases, like when using the Logger package, you can just send messages from the isolate to the main thread and call the logger there.

Check out the easy_isolate plugin, it provides an easy way to work with isolates and well-explained documentation

https://pub.dev/packages/easy_isolate